# capability of ffmpeg under lgpl

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to implement something like:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp://xxx -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f rtsp rtsp://xxx
```

The code is very similar to [this example](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/remuxing_8c-example.html). Can this be done using only LGPL part of ffmpeg ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964). Open source licensing questions can be asked on [OpenSource.SE](//opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Machavity this is not a licensing question - it's not asking about legal provisions or execution. It's asking if the components required for executing the OP's API calls are unavailable if the license is not LGPL. That evaluation is made by ffmpeg's configure shell script and does not involve any engagement with the law. Imagine that ffmpeg offered three build options: lite, standard and full. The OP's question is tantamount to asking if they could carry out their requirements with the lite build. That's the crux of it. That the qualifying parameter is legal, is accidental.

Comment: @Mulvya I've removed the GPL and LGPL tags and voted to reopen. In the future, if someone mistags these, could you help fix that? For those of us not involved with ffmpeg these look like licensing questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are sure there will be no decoding or encoding, it shouldn't be an issue. Most native components are LGPL.

Some of the filters and their dependents are GPL, but you aren't using any. 
Since you can't use any filters, you won't be able to do things like alter PTS using (a)setpts filters, or use the fps/framerate filters. Few of the demuxers for synthetic music files are third-party libs but they are LGPL.